# how to create a row for each corresponding column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame which formatted like this:

| - | Name | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | John | object 1 | object 2 | Object 3 | object 4 |
| 1 | Smith | object 1 | object 2 | Object 3 | object 4 |
| 2 | Jack | object 1 | object 2 | Object 3 | object 4 |

and I want to transform it to the following:

| - | Name | 0 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | John | object1 |
| 1 | John | object2 |
| 2 | John | object3 |
| 3 | John | object4 |
| 4 | Smith | object1 |
| 5 | Smith | object2 |
| 6 | Smith | object3 |
| 7 | Smith | object4 |
| 8 | Jack | object1 |
| 9 | Jack | object2 |
| 10 | Jack | object3 |
| 11 | Jack | object4 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = (pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Name'], value_vars=df.columns[1:])
 .drop(columns=['variable'])
 .sort_values(by='Name')
 .pipe(lambda g: g.set_axis(np.arange(0, len(g.index)), axis=0)))

df

     Name     value
0    Jack  object 1
1    Jack  object 2
2    Jack  Object 3
3    Jack  object 4
4    John  object 1
5    John  object 2
6    John  Object 3
7    John  object 4
8   Smith  object 1
9   Smith  object 2
10  Smith  Object 3
11  Smith  object 4
```